# php get json item return wrong

Tags: php, json

I have the following code with my php(updated):

$sql = "INSERT INTO uac_user (user_name, user_password, create_time, lastupdateTime) VALUES ('$usernmae', '$password', NOW(), NOW())";

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id; //get new id
    $records = array();  //select role
    if($result = $conn->query("SELECT role_id FROM uac_role WHERE `role_name` = '$role';")){
        if($result->num_rows){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $records = $row;
            }
            $dateResult=(string)json_encode($records);
            echo ($dateResult);
            echo ($dateResult['role_id']);
            // $sql2 = "INSERT INTO uac_mapping (role_id, user_id) VALUES ('$dateResult['role_id']', '$last_id')"; //insert mapping
            // if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
                // echo "success"; 
            // }
            // else {
                // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            // }
        }
        else $records = 'no data';
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
die();
```

the first echo return [{"role_id":"4"}]

but the second return [

what I need for the second  one is 4

what is the problem about my code?

Comment: Add the `$records` array exactly as it is. It's easier to pinpoint the problem that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made a common mistake of confusing what JSON is and is not. JSON is a way of representing some data in a string, for transfer to another system, where it will be turned back into something else for use. JSON is *not* a type of object that you can use directly to extract data.

Look carefully at this line:

```
$dateResult=(string)json_encode($records);
```

The result of this is that `$dateResult` is a string - you even have an extra `(string)`, but even without that, [the manual page for `json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) makes clear that you will always have a string:

> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of the supplied value.

You then run this:

```
$dateResult[role_id]
```

You are trying to look up `role_id` *inside a string*. But a string is just a bunch of symbols, it doesn't know what "role_id" is. You had structured data in `$records`, it's there that you want to look up `role_id`.

If `$records` is an array, what you want is `$records['role_id']` (note the quotes around `'role_id'`; `role_id` would be the name of a constant, not a string).

If `$records` is an object, what you want is `$records->role_id` (no quotes this time, because `->role_id` is more like a variable name than a string).

Comment: I just updated the code and the $records is an array
I have tried both of 'role_id'; role_id but it doesn't work

Comment: @WaiHung Read my answer again. You do not need `json_encode` here, you do not need `$dateResult`, you do not need anything to do with JSON. Also, the function name "fetch_object" should give you a clue that what it will return is in fact an object.

Comment: I just use echo ($records->role_id); and it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your json is probably an array of objects, so you can loop through them and use something like:

```
echo $dateResult[$counter]->role_id;
//$counter will be your loop incrementer;
```

Comment: but it does not return 4